# How to get a hover effect to only show up over a link and not a containers whole width

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with the hover of my links. I have the parent, container element set to `32%` width, this is causing my hover for my links to create a pointer and/or to be selected when the user isn't over the link. I have tried to set the link (`#state-list-left a`, etc., etc.) to `width: auto` and this did not help. I have also tried to change the HTML and put it within a list item, like this:

`<a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php"><li>Alabama</li></a>`

How can I get the link to only be clicked on over the words?

```css
#state-list-left,
#state-list-middle,
#state-list-right {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#state-list-left a,
#state-list-middle a,
#state-list-right a {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#state-list-left a:hover,
#state-list-middle a:hover,
#state-list-right a:hover {
  color: #0C3;
}
```

```html
<div id="state-list-left">
  <a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alabama</a>
  <a href="Alaska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alaska</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `display: block;` from the `a` css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `float: left;` and `clear: left;` on `<a>` elements.

`float: left;` will align the elements to the left and `clear: left;` to bring the next link on the next line.

```css
#state-list-left,
#state-list-middle,
#state-list-right {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#state-list-left a,
#state-list-middle a,
#state-list-right a {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  float: left; /* Add this */
  clear: both; /* Add this */
  text-decoration: none;
}
#state-list-left a:hover,
#state-list-middle a:hover,
#state-list-right a:hover {
  color: #0C3;
}
```

```html
<div id="state-list-left">
  <a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alabama</a>
  <a href="Alaska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alaska</a>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To set the links center aligned, each `<a>` can be wrapped in `<div>`.

```css
#find-contractor-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#find-contractor-container {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px 10%;
}

#find-contractor {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0 40px 0;
}

#find-contractor-button {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background: #cc3300;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

#find-contractor-button:hover {
    background: #0C3;
    border: none;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

#find-contractor a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

#state-list-left,
#state-list-middle,
#state-list-right {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 32%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#state-list-left div,
#state-list-middle div,
#state-list-right div {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#state-list-left a,
#state-list-middle a,
#state-list-right a {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#state-list-left a:hover,
#state-list-middle a:hover,
#state-list-right a:hover {
    color: #0C3;
}

#state-list-middle {
    text-align: center;
}

#state-list-right {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p id="find-contractor-message">Spray Foam Equipment Insider, your number one advertising and marketing resource. Proudly serving all 50 states and Canada:</p>
<div id="find-contractor-container">
    <div id="find-contractor"><a href="Find-local-spray-foam-polyurea-contractors.php"><span id="find-contractor-button">FIND A CONTRACTOR</span></a></div>
    <div id="state-list-left">
        <div><a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alabama</a></div>
        <div><a href="Alaska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alaska</a></div>
        <div><a href="Arizona-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Arizona</a></div>
        <div><a href="Arkansas-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Arkansas</a></div>
        <div><a href="California-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">California</a></div>
        <div><a href="Colorado-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Colorado</a></div>
        <div><a href="Connecticut-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Connecticut</a></div>
        <div><a href="Delaware-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Delaware</a></div>
        <div><a href="Florida-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Florida</a></div>
        <div><a href="Georgia-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Georgia</a></div>
        <div><a href="Hawaii- Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Hawaii</a></div>
        <div><a href="Idaho-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Idaho</a></div>
        <div><a href="Illinois-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Illinois</a></div>
        <div><a href="Indiana-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Indiana</a></div>
        <div><a href="Iowa-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Iowa</a></div>
        <div><a href="Kansas-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Kansas</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="state-list-middle">
        <div><a href="Kentucky-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Kentucky</a></div>
        <div><a href="Louisiana-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Louisiana</a></div>
        <div><a href="Maine-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Maine</a></div>
        <div><a href="Maryland-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Maryland</a></div>
        <div><a href="Massachusetts-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Massachusetts</a></div>
        <div><a href="Michigan-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Michigan</a></div>
        <div><a href="Minnesota-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Minnesota</a></div>
        <div><a href="Mississippi-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Mississippi</a></div>
        <div><a href="Missouri-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Missouri</a></div>
        <div><a href="Montana-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Montana</a></div>
        <div><a href="Nebraska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Nebraska</a></div>
        <div><a href="New-Hampshire-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">New Hampshire</a></div>
        <div><a href="New-Jersey-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">New Jersey</a></div>
        <div><a href="New-Mexico-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">New Mexico</a></div>
        <div><a href="New-York-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">New York</a></div>
        <div><a href="North-Carolina-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">North Carolina</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="state-list-right">
        <div><a href="North-Dakota-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">North Dakota</a></div>
        <div><a href="Ohio-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Ohio</a></div>
        <div><a href="Oklahoma-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Oklahoma</a></div>
        <div><a href="Oregon-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Oregon</a></div>
        <div><a href="Pennsylvania-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Pennsylvania</a></div>
        <div><a href="Rhode-Island-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Rhode Island</a></div>
        <div><a href="South-Carolina-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">South Carolina</a></div>
        <div><a href="South-Dakota-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">South Dakota</a></div>
        <div><a href="Tennessee-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Tennessee</a></div>
        <div><a href="Texas-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Texas</a></div>
        <div><a href="Utah-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Utah</a></div>
        <div><a href="Vermont-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Vermont</a></div>
        <div><a href="Virginia-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Virginia</a></div>
        <div><a href="Washington-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Washington</a></div>
        <div><a href="West-Virginia-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">West Virginia</a></div>
        <div><a href="Wisconsin-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Wisconsin</a></div>
        <div><a href="Wyoming-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Wyoming</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this works for the most part, but it made my elements shift to the left some. There are three blocks total, and now they aren't centered. I added a pic in the question.

Comment: It seems like the `text-align`s are not working for the center and right one.

Comment: @Becky Add `text-align: center;` on container. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6k9fa2Lc/2/). Note that I haven't changed `text-align` of Right list as it was manually set to `right` align.

Comment: It's not working for me the same way as it is for you.

Comment: @Becky Some confusion here. You want to make the lists center aligned, right? I've added demo in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but you removed your `float: left` and `clear: both` which makes me come back to my original issue of the links not only being clickable when hovering over the text with the link.

Comment: @Becky Not sure if there is another better way without changing the HTML structure. [By wrapping each anchor in `<div>` the problem can be solved](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6k9fa2Lc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing inline block on your link but you will also seperate each link with you div

```css
#state-list-left,
#state-list-middle,
#state-list-right {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#state-list-left a,
#state-list-middle a,
#state-list-right a {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#state-list-left a:hover,
#state-list-middle a:hover,
#state-list-right a:hover {
  color: #0C3;
}
```

```html
<div id="state-list-left">
  <div><a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alabama</a></div>
  <div><a href="Alaska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alaska</a></div>
</div>

<div id="state-list-middle">
  <div><a href="Alabama-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alabama</a></div>
  <div><a href="Alaska-Spray-Foam-Insulation.php">Alaska</a></div>
</div>
```